# Validating the percent variance explained of principal components on out-of-sample data

Tags: pca, bootstrap, dimensionality-reduction, validation

I'm trying to ascertain whether the variance explained by a certain PCA on an out-of-sample dataset is not due to random chance.

Suppose I have a dataset X with size n-x-p, and I run a PCA and obtain the p-x-p matrix W of coefficients. I obtain another dataset Y with size m-x-p, and I project the values of Y onto the principal axes of the 1st dataset X by W*X. I am able to obtain the variance explained by calculating the ratio of the variance of the residuals and actual variance of Y. We are assuming that X and Y are drawn from a population following a normal distribution.

Now, I want to know whether the variance explained by these PCs on Y is not just due to random chance.

*My attempt:*

I've tried bootstrapping the original dataset X and running PCA on the bootstrapped dataset and projected Y onto those new PCs. I calculate the percent variance explained by from each bootstrapped PCA, and they are fairly close to the initial calculated % variance explained.

Now to know what the percent variance explained due to random chance, I shuffle the original dataset X several times, and run the PCA on these. I expect that the value of the percent variance explained is 1/p. However, when I do this calculation with my out-of-sample dataset, I am now getting negative values for the percent variance explained.

So there is clearly an error in my approach. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify your bootstrap approach.  The Efron-Gong optimism bootstrap (i.e., using the bootstrap to estimate bias in a quantity such as $R^2$ or proportion of variance explained by $PC_1$) involves estimating parameters in one of many bootstrap samples and applying these parameters to the original whole dataset.   In your setting the parameters involve the loadings of $PC_1$.  These loadings are also a function of the pre-analysis standard deviations that you have to estimate to use $PC$s in the usual way.  So you'd also be validating the normalization stage simultaneously with validating the loadings on the standardized quantities.

I'm glad you are considering the volatility of $PC$ because most analysts act as if the loadings are estimated without error.  By following the full bias-estimating bootstrap procedure (and I hope you provide code that all of us can benefit from) you average over a few hundred bootstrap resamples this quantity: proportion of variance explained in a bootstrap sample minus what that same set of loadings explains in the original sample.  Then you subject that average optimism from the original apparent proportion explained to get a bias-corrected estimate of the proportion.  This estimates the likely future performance of your original $PC_1$.